# AOSP Automotive Orientation Change Not Working

Tags: android, orientation, android-source

I have build the AOSP Automotive emulator, but it is in landscape mode, I am trying to change the orientation to portrait, by referring to this link [AOSP Automotive orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56048529/aosp-automotive-orientation-change) . I also tried changing the `hw.initialOrientation` property in the `config.ini` file, but that is also not working. Using the `adb shell settings put system user_rotation 0` command works only on the emulator and not on the hardware. How to change the orientation in AOSP Automotive?